# How to add new user to Kamailio using PHP shell_exec?

Tags: php, mysql, shell, kamailio

There is a requirement to add a new user to **Kamailio** programmatically using **PHP**. I tried to add username and password to ***subscriber*** table manually using **SQL** queries, but it won't works because **ha1** and **ha1b** should be added to the table. I don't know how Kamailio generate **ha1** and **ha1b**. Following are the manually added entries using **kamctl** tool.

```html
mysql> select * from subscriber limit 2;
+----+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------+
| id | username | domain        | password     | email_address | ha1                              | ha1b                             | rpid |
+----+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------+
|  9 | 1010101  | 10.101.101.10 | aswwwwwwwsdf |               | a37d1785953310c206481ca1a33f16b6 | 7e981130f05a547a738d3c29031e89d0 | NULL |
| 10 | 1010102  | 10.101.101.10 | 6eeeeee8a72  |               | 6b574f9047206481ca1a33501d7dbdce | cd9a8b89d926f3cb1290311a8cb8a2a8 | NULL |
+----+----------+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+------+
```

Then I tried with **shell_exec** function in **PHP** to use **kamctl** command(***kamctl add username password***). but it will prompt for **Kamailio** read-write user's password. So following command cannot add new users to Kamailio

```
$res = shell_exec("sudo kamctl add new_username new_password);
```

so, please suggest a way to add new user's to **Kamailio** programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about how to provide the password for the prompt coming after the **add** command.
Here is the solution, you can use **echo** to pass the password to the prompt and you can use a **pipe** right before your actual command. So that the prompt will get the echoed password and it will add a new user.

```
$res = shell_exec("echo password |kamctl add new_username new_password");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add to subscriber table in Kamailio database if you are using php to create user accounts. ha1b is nothing but md5 hash of username, realm , password details . kamailio subscriber table structure is like below .[image]